# why i can't replace string with variable with sed

Tags: bash, sed

```
echo -n  "Username: "
read usernamert
echo -n "Password: "
read passwordt
echo -n "IP: "
read IPt
echo -n  "Channel: "
read channelt

t1=$(echo "www://$usernamet:$passwordt@$IPt/TEST/SOMETHING?channel=$channelt1&TRUE=1")

sed -i "s+"t_1", "t_2"+"$t1", "AAA"+g" test.txt
```

link should looks like
www://username:password@$1.1.1.1/TEST/SOMETHING?channel=2&TRUE=1

so this kind of link i want to change with string in file test.txt

> "t_1", "t_2"

but allways gets error. Where I mistake? I also tried to put variables in "" inside t1 variable, but didnt help.

Comment: If you need to match `"` literally, you need to escape it: `\"`

Comment: when i add that escape ONLY with " and echo it i get this(with all user inputs)

"www://username:password@$1.1.1.1/TEST/SOMETHING?channel=2&TRUE=1"

and i uncomment sed command to test it, and there is no errors, but when cat file, it still exist this string "t_1", "t_2", instead of that www.....

Comment: It's easier if you use single quotes: `sed 's+"t_1", "t_2"+"'"$t1"'", "AAA"+g'`

Comment: Just switch to double quotes around the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your double quotes are delimiting the shell strings, not being used literally in the `sed` pattern and replacement.

Put single quotes around the `sed` operation, except for the variable.

```
sed -i 's+"t_1", "t_2"+"'"$t1"'", "AAA"+g' test.txt
```